# Second Y-axis labelling in cognos chart

Tags: charts, cognos, cognos-10, linegraph

I have a simple line graph that shows daily pricing for 3 months. I need another Y-axis on the right to be label as the same scale on the left. How can it be done?

I'm now using secondary axis to do this which will have 2 lines overlapping together which is ok as it does not affect my graph. However it shows an extra element for that secondary axis in the legend. How can it be removed?

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the customizer and go to chart properties in order to see if you can use second Y axis labelling or not.